# php-fpm doesn't load kafka extension while php cli does

Tags: php, apache-kafka

I compile php kafka extension as [this link](https://github.com/EVODelavega/phpkafka) says.

I can use `Kafka` Class in php cli mode but get an `Class 'Kafka' not found` error in php-fpm(web request) mode.

`php --info | grep kafka` indicate the extension is present while `phpinfo` in html   indicate the extension the is absent.

I can confirm from the `phpinfo page` that php-fpm and php-cli use the same php.ini.

So, How can I spot where the problem is ?

php version :  5.5.13
php-fpm version : 5.5.13

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer.

The `Class 'Kafka' not found` error in php-fpm mode is caused by php-fpm unable to load Kafka extension. Although I add `extension=kafka.so` in `php.ini`. But some error occured while loading the extension.

I found the reason by use `dl` to load the extension manually, and get error in the response. Why does the php-fpm keep silent while some error occured in the process of loading extension. Maybe I missed some configuration?

Anyway, the reason is found. Php-fpm can't load librdkafka while load extension kafka. The librdkafka is in the dir `/usr/local/lib`, which is not in the ld search path in red-hat. Check /etc/ld.so.conf for your search path.

Add `/usr/local/lib` to /etc/ld.so.conf and run ldconfig solve the problem.

The reason why cli mode worked is because the variable $LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib".

For more info about the loading process, check [this link](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)

> The list of directories to be searched is stored in the file /etc/ld.so.conf. Many Red Hat-derived distributions don't normally include /usr/local/lib in the file /etc/ld.so.conf. I consider this a bug, and adding /usr/local/lib to /etc/ld.so.conf is a common ``fix'' required to run many programs on Red Hat-derived systems.
>
> Searching all of these directories at program start-up would be grossly inefficient, so a caching arrangement is actually used. The program ldconfig(8) by default reads in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, sets up the appropriate symbolic links in the dynamic link directories (so they'll follow the standard conventions), and then writes a cache to /etc/ld.so.cache that's then used by other programs. This greatly speeds up access to libraries. The implication is that ldconfig must be run whenever a DLL is added, when a DLL is removed, or when the set of DLL directories changes; running ldconfig is often one of the steps performed by package managers when installing a library. On start-up, then, the dynamic loader actually uses the file /etc/ld.so.cache and then loads the libraries it needs.

The install guide in [github](https://github.com/EVODelavega/phpkafka) menthioned about run ldconfig, but red-hat has the special situatiion the lib dir is not in the ld config  file.